# Загрузка файлов на сервер с прогрессом

Tags: node.js, потоки-данных, fileupload

Я пытаюсь загрузить файлы на сервер таким образом (ниже приведены части трех файлов, роутер, контроллер и скрипт который грузит файлы):

```
///router
var multipart = require("connect-multiparty");
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
//.....
router.post("/save", multipartMiddleware, function(req, res, next) {
    var s = new Settings(res,req);
    s.saveSection();
});


//controller
var File = require('fileuploader');
//more action
    this.saveSection = function(){
//more action
        var files = new File(req.files);
            log.info(req.files);
            files.moveUploadedFiles(FOLDER,function(upload){
                //moreactions...
            });
    };



//uploader
//moreactions....
this.moveUploadedFiles = function(dest,cb){
        async.waterfall ([
            function (cb) {
                $this.createFolder(dest,function(){
                    cb(null);
                });
            }
        ], function () {
            var infile = [];
            var outfile = [];
            var uploadSize = [];

            for (var i in files) {
                (function(i) {
                    var path = dest + '/' + files[i].originalFilename;
                    infile[i] = fs.createReadStream(files[i].path);
                    outfile[i] = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                    infile[i].on('data',function(data) {
                        if(!uploadSize[i]){
                            uploadSize[i] = 0;
                        }
                        uploadSize[i] += data.length/1024;
                        console.log(files[i].originalFilename + ': '+parseInt(uploadSize[i])+'/'+(parseInt(files[i].size/1024)) + ' Kb');
                    });
                    infile[i].pipe(outfile[i]);
                })(i);
            }
            return cb(1); 
        });
    };
```

Суть в том что, файлы сначала прогружаются, а потом приходит ответ и я вижу в консоли прогресс копирования их из временной директории в целевую.
Как сделать stream на входе где-нибудь в контроллере или на уровне роутера, не знаю как лучше, но по-мойму лучше делать это в скрипте uploader. Т.е. задача в том, чтобы в момент сабмита формы, сразу начиналась загрузка с помощью stream, для того чтобы этот прогресс можно было выводить, а не так как сейчас - я вижу прогресс копирования файла уже когда он на сервере... Как это реализовать? Может быть в пределах одного запроса, передаваемые файлы есть возможность читать асинхронно? или это не возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю, что Вы неверно используете `async.waterfall`.
В целом не понятно, в чём именно у Вас проблема. Но если Вам нужно, чтобы файлы копировались асинхронно, и после того, как все файлы будут скопированы, вызывалась какая-то функция, попробуйте переписать `this.moveUploadedFiles` (я не знаю, что такое `files`, и если это ассоциативный массив, а не `Array`, просто сделайте предварительно из него `Array`):

```js
this.moveUploadedFiles = function(dest, callback){
async.waterfall ([
    function (cb) {
        $this.createFolder(dest,function(){
            cb(null);
        });
    }, function (cb) {
        async.each(files, function(file, next) {
            var path = dest + '/' + file.originalFilename;
            var totalSize = file.size / 1024;
            var ws = fs.createWriteStream(path);
            ws.on('error', function(err) {
                next('Ошибка при записи файла ' + path + ' (' + err + ')');
            });
            var uploadSize = 0;                
            var rs = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
            rs.on('data', function(data) {
                uploadSize += data.length;
                console.log(file.originalFilename + ': '
                            + (uploadSize / 1024) + '/'
                            + totalSize + ' Kb');
            });
            rs.on('error', function() {
                next('Ошибка при чтении файла ' + path + ' (' + err + ')');
            });
            rs.on('end', function() {
                console.log('A file', path, 'processed');
                next(null, file);
            });
            rs.pipe(ws);
        }, function(err) {
            if(err) console.log('Failed to process', err);
            else console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
            cb();
        });
    }
], function (err) {
    callback();
});
};
```

Comment: files - это объект содержащий данные о файлах (req.files из multiparty), async тут ни при чем, суть задачи подробнее некуда, изложил в комментарии к посту @Pavel Mayorov выше

Comment: Я понимаю, что `async` не главная проблема. Но всё-таки Вы неправильное его используете.
Но в чём Ваша проблема всё-таки не ясно. Вы хотите на сервере видеть процесс заливки файла? Наподобие того, как это выглядит в клиенте?

Comment: да, процесс заливки файла на сервер. А в моем примере показан процесс копирования файла из временной папки в целевую

Comment: Тогда Вам должна помочь [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-file-upload)

Comment: Это ясно что тут socket.io нужен, но перед этим нужно хотя бы в консоль вывести процесс заливки файла на сервер!

Answer (score -1):

Выглядит так, будто `multiparty` не умеет откладывать чтение файла. И, в общем-то, понятно почему так происходит: браузер всегда может поставить остальные данные формы уже после файла - и тогда вы не сможете никак определить, куда сохранять файл, не прочитав его предварительно.

Выходом может стать отказ от `multiparty` и от стандартных форм браузера. Можно перехватить событие отправки формы на клиенте, и отправить запрос на сервер альтернативным способом - вынести часть параметров в строку запроса или в заголовки HTTP. Тогда в теле запроса не останется ничего кроме самого файла, и его можно будет прочитать из потока запроса асинхронно.

Comment: Нет-нет, вы наверняка не поняли суть проблемы, или быть может я некорректно изложил ее в вопросе. Проблема не в том что я ожидаю пока файл запишется (т.е. прийдет вместе со всеми данными в форме), здесь не нужно делать один отдельный запрос содержащий только файлы например. Когда данные формы приходят на сервер, по умолчанию файл помещается во временную папку, далее мы уже что-то с ним делаем... так вот, основной момент в задаче - вывести в консоль прогресс записи файла из формы во временную папку с помощью stream